# Syntax Error: Comma in Query Expression of SQL Statement Access?

Tags: ms-access

I've been trying to make this statement work for some time but have ultimately lost the will to live.

In essence, I am attempting to filter a report to only certain Locations (So if you want the query to only include locations "Avonmouth" and "Bedford", that's what it would include, filtering the rest out) I have done this by implementing a check box system, so you can easily add locations to the filter. Unfortunately I keep getting syntax problems with the SQL script. Its a bit of a butchery, so please forgive me, but I have included the SQL below. (CHKBE = The check box)

> WHERE QryTraining IN ((IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKAV]<>"" ,"Avonmouth",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBA]<>"" ,"Basingstoke",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBT]<>"" ,"Bedford Transport",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBW]<>"" ,"Bedford Warehouse",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBE]<>"" ,"Belfast",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKCA]<>"" ,"Carluke",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKEX]<>"" ,"Exeter",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKKI]<>"" ,"Kidderminister",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKKN]<>"" ,
>   "Knowsley",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKTE]<>"" ,"Teva",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKWI]<>"" ,"Wickford",x),(IIf [Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKYO]<>"" ,"York",x))

Each time I attempt to run it, it throws it back with a Syntax error.

Thanks in advance, T.

Comment: Is this from a dynamic parameterized query object? I NEVER use them. I prefer VBA to construct criteria string and apply to form Filter property or the WHERE argument of OpenForm/OpenReport. Instead of a bunch of checkboxes, I would use a multi-select listbox and VBA to construct the IN parameters string. What is x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will work any better but parens are in wrong place at beginning of each IIf() and maybe need apostrophe delimiters:

`WHERE QryTraining IN (IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKAV]<>"" ,"'Avonmouth'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBA]<>"","'Basingstoke'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBT]<>"","'Bedford Transport'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBW]<>"","'Bedford Warehouse'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKBE]<>"","'Belfast'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKCA]<>"","'Carluke'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKEX]<>"","'Exeter'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKKI]<>"","'Kidderminister'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKKN]<>"","'Knowsley'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKTE]<>"","'Teva'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKWI]<>"","'Wickford'",x), IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKYO]<>"","'York'",x))`

Probably need to use empty string or some text like `"N/A"` in place of the `x`.

A BOUND checkbox must be either True or False (Yes/No), never an empty string. An UNBOUND checkbox can be set for triple state, in which case it could return True/False/Null, again never an empty string. So I am not sure why comparison to empty string. Just test for True.
`IIf([Forms]![ReportDeployer]![CHKAV], "'Avonmouth'", "")`

Comment: x was just meant to mean a non value that wouldn't affect the filter

Comment: Also, Just tried this and it pretty much worked! The x is causing problems though...

Comment: Not surprising. Try an empty string instead.